# format string from Date.getTime()

Tags: javascript

For some reason I can't find the answer to how to format a string from new Date().getTime().

When I run this string, I get a sequence of numbers such as 1395430135200.

How do I format this back into a readable date with time zone?

Comment: Have you really tried to find [an answer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the UNIX time as a parameter to a new date object and can then use `.toString()` to get a readable interpretation. Like this:

```
new Date(1395430135200).toString()
// "Fri Mar 21 2014 20:28:55 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)"
```

Comment: thanks Daniel! is there any way to format this in detail? such as omit seconds, change timezone

Comment: @Allen Like Teemu mentioned in a comment to your first post, if you visit [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) you can see all the methods of the `Date` object, like `getMonth()`, `getMinutes()` etc. You can use that to make any String you want.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use new Date()?

```
var now = new Date();
console.log(now.toLocaleDateString());
console.log(now.toLocaleTimeString());
```

Comment: becasue I'm storing the date to the database, thus needing a date that isn't "now"

Comment: I think the use of "now" was just an example Allen. The important bit was the use of `toLocaleDateString()` and `toLocaleTimeString()` on any date.

Comment: Sorry Allen.  In your original question you said, "new Date().getTime()" -- assumed you were working solely on dates client side.